# How to get declaring type of an atrribute from sub types tree in C#

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I spend a lot of times to find how to get the type which declare the attribute in sub type hierarchy, but no find out any way yet, hope any one know how to help me.

Example we have some stuffs as below:

I have a attribute class to define name of table if needed

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TableBaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name;
}
```

then i can use it as

```cs
[TableBase] // when not assign Name, will get name of the type which declare attribute, in this case is 'Customer'
class Customer
{

}

class CustomerProxy : Customer
{

}
```

and

```cs
[TableBase(Name = "_USER")]
class User
{

}

class UserRBAC : User
{

}

class UserRBACProxy : UserRBAC
{

}
```

so now, how to solve this

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Table of CustomerProxy is : {0}", GetTableNameFromType(typeof(CustomerProxy)));
        Console.WriteLine("Table of UserProxy is : {0}", GetTableNameFromType(typeof(UserRBACProxy)));
    }

    static string GetTableNameFromType(Type type)
    {
        // what go here to get string of "Customer" for type = CustomerProxy
        //              to get string of "_USER" for type = UserRBACProxy

        TableBaseAttribute tableBaseA = (TableBaseAttribute)typeof(CustomerProxy).GetCustomAttributes(type, true)[0];

        string ret = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableBaseA.Name))
            ret = ???
        else
            ret = tableBaseA.Name;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you correctly. You want the name of the type on which the attribute is declared, right? If so, this should work:

```
    static string GetTableNameFromType(Type type)
    {
        // what go here to get string of "Customer" for type = CustomerProxy
        //              to get string of "_USER" for type = UserRBACProxy

        TableBaseAttribute tableBaseA = (TableBaseAttribute)type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableBaseAttribute), true)[0];

        string ret = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableBaseA.Name))
        {
            do
            {
                var attr = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableBaseAttribute), false);
                if (attr.Length > 0)
                {
                    return type.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    type = type.BaseType;
                }
            } while (type != typeof(object));
        }
        else
        {
            ret = tableBaseA.Name;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the type when no attribute override is specified, this will give you the class name only

```
ret = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tableBaseA.Name) ? type.Name : tableBaseA.Name;
```

---

I just realised that the above would not work in the context of pulling the `TableBase` decorated type class name but instead take the *current* type class name. In that case, you will need to work your way up the inheritance tree to find that base class

```
var baseType = type.BaseType;
while (baseType != null)
{
    var attrs = baseType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableBaseAttribute), false);
    if (attrs.Length > 0) 
    {
        ret = baseType.Name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have attributes against a class, Only properties in the class can have an attribute property.  An XML attribute will have an equal sign in the XML file while an element doesn't have an equal sign.  Post sample of XML data.

Comment: @jdweng 2 things, Firstly, you certainly can have attributes against a class, attribute scope is dictated by the `AttributeTargets` enum. Secondly, what has this got to do with XML?

Comment: In this scope your type is CustomerProxy, doing type.Name will return CustomerProxy and not the name of the base class.

Comment: That's what I was thinking @Brduca. How to get the type decorated with the attribute? Thinking that you could have multiple levels of inheritance

Comment: @Brduca ah, good spot I just realised that the OP was using `CustomerProxy` and not `Customer`. This somewhat complicates matters though because unless there is a strict rule about what class name should be used as the default then it's difficult to know how far up the inheritance tree we need to go.